# Cannot open this GeoJSON in QGIS 2.10

Tags: qgis, geojson

I have this home made GeoJSON:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[2.28313, 48.84024], [2.28297, 48.84011], [2.28282, 48.83993], [2.28186, 48.83953], [2.28141, 48.83933], [2.28114, 48.83908], [2.28081, 48.83889], [2.28016, 48.83769], [2.28089, 48.83734], [2.28135, 48.83738], [2.28158, 48.83734], [2.28178, 48.83744], [2.2827, 48.83737], [2.28207, 48.83795], [2.28245, 48.83843], [2.28287, 48.83877], [2.28321, 48.83947], [2.28418, 48.83959], [2.28365, 48.84018]], [[2.30497, 48.85573], [2.30372, 48.85534], [2.30395, 48.85439], [2.30407, 48.8541], [2.3037, 48.85309], [2.30411, 48.85302], [2.30486, 48.85336], [2.30494, 48.85341], [2.305, 48.85345], [2.30511, 48.85344], [2.30653, 48.85357], [2.30677, 48.85343], [2.30729, 48.85352], [2.30721, 48.85408], [2.30728, 48.85489], [2.30689, 48.8546], [2.30641, 48.85495], [2.30618, 48.85513], [2.30535, 48.85534], [2.30524, 48.85527]], [[2.28558, 48.83979], [2.28588, 48.83992], [2.28626, 48.8397], [2.28678, 48.83965], [2.28686, 48.83972], [2.28731, 48.83976], [2.28749, 48.83973], [2.28781, 48.83954], [2.28801, 48.83946], [2.28841, 48.83901], [2.28845, 48.83879], [2.28833, 48.83831], [2.28894, 48.83803], [2.28913, 48.83795], [2.28935, 48.83785], [2.29016, 48.83879], [2.29142, 48.83872], [2.29173, 48.83859], [2.29208, 48.83861], [2.29219, 48.83865], [2.29276, 48.8383], [2.2926, 48.83878], [2.29305, 48.83869], [2.29374, 48.83866], [2.29484, 48.83865], [2.2961, 48.83845], [2.2963, 48.83832], [2.29684, 48.83836], [2.29725, 48.83828], [2.2975, 48.83832], [2.29767, 48.83841], [2.29844, 48.83832], [2.29837, 48.83926], [2.29875, 48.83946], [2.29966, 48.84026], [2.29944, 48.84055], [2.2999, 48.8407], [2.29997, 48.84072], [2.30018, 48.84116], [2.30054, 48.84145], [2.30089, 48.84157], [2.3026, 48.84274], [2.30241, 48.84374], [2.30122, 48.84406], [2.30071, 48.84412], [2.30032, 48.84448], [2.29944, 48.84538], [2.29976, 48.84621], [2.29989, 48.84649], [2.3014, 48.8478], [2.30137, 48.84783], [2.30135, 48.84787], [2.30116, 48.84818], [2.30061, 48.84863], [2.30061, 48.84866], [2.30027, 48.84915], [2.30044, 48.84958], [2.30057, 48.85022], [2.30046, 48.85084], [2.30044, 48.85085], [2.30008, 48.85086], [2.29894, 48.85067], [2.29881, 48.8506], [2.29817, 48.85087], [2.29746, 48.85075], [2.2974, 48.85074], [2.29701, 48.85069], [2.29629, 48.85058], [2.29564, 48.85066], [2.29517, 48.85006], [2.29453, 48.85014], [2.29461, 48.84941], [2.29472, 48.84851], [2.29508, 48.84791], [2.29413, 48.8484], [2.29407, 48.84833], [2.29369, 48.84833], [2.29269, 48.84911], [2.29279, 48.84858], [2.29276, 48.84854], [2.29279, 48.84825], [2.29196, 48.84789], [2.29166, 48.84793], [2.2907, 48.84779], [2.29038, 48.84775], [2.28971, 48.84763], [2.28922, 48.8476], [2.28854, 48.84757], [2.28798, 48.84741], [2.2874, 48.84737], [2.28678, 48.84714], [2.28628, 48.84701], [2.28614, 48.84697], [2.28592, 48.84709], [2.28539, 48.84687], [2.28516, 48.84652], [2.28512, 48.84617], [2.28558, 48.84623], [2.28582, 48.84624], [2.28591, 48.84625], [2.28598, 48.84604], [2.28586, 48.84583], [2.28589, 48.84544], [2.28531, 48.84524], [2.28535, 48.84469], [2.28539, 48.84415], [2.2859, 48.84252], [2.28506, 48.8424], [2.28505, 48.84162], [2.28521, 48.84068], [2.28499, 48.84058], [2.28481, 48.83984], [2.28545, 48.83969]], [[2.30982, 48.85636], [2.31054, 48.85769], [2.31001, 48.85807], [2.30963, 48.85765], [2.30951, 48.85756], [2.30943, 48.85711]]]]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"value": "0.0"}}]}
```

When trying it on http://geojsonlint.com/, my multipolygon is properly displayed. However when I open it with QGIS 2.10, nothing is displayed.

Is there anything wrong with this file? Is this a QGIS bug?

---

I've added another layer with a few roads just to make sure I was well centred. Strange thing, when zooming out suddenly the multipolygon appeared. I can only see it at this level of zoom and there is this weird line getting out of it... weird behaviour.

[image]

---

@ThomasB pointed out the errors in the JSON. I've tried to open the corrected version he put online and I get a blank screen. But playing around with the zoom, adding and removing the layer, suddenly again a shape was displayed...

[image]

I've seen that he is using QGIS 2.10 as well but I do not know his OS.

Comment: The GeoJSON works fine in my QGIS `2.10.1` as well as in `ogrinfo`. Can you elaborate on "Nothing is displayed" - everything looks good on my end.

Comment: The attribute table is empty, there should be one feature with value 0.0.

Comment: I open QGIS, double click on the file from the left panel under Home (I'm on Ubuntu). Then I see the file being added to the layer list, but the main screen remains blank. I've tried to right click, zoom to layer but I can't see any shape.

Comment: What CRS has the layer, as reported by Rightclick -> Set Layer CRS?

Comment: WGS 84 (+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs)

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the rendering problems have something to do with errors in your layer.
I checked the geometry validity and there are 8 errors.
The attribute value "value: 0,0" is displayed correct in the attribute table.
The only problem i saw in QGIS 2.10 was that QGIS could not label the layer but this could have something to do with the geometry that is not valid.

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
So here a bit more information:
Your linear rings are not closed. The first and the last coordinate of the linear ring must be the exact same coordinate.
Apart from that I added one more square bracket for each polygon in order not to get any confusion with inner and outer rings.

Now the labeling also works in QGIS 2.10:

[image]

Here you can find the corrected geojson to give it a try in your QGIS:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d63b83bf134aa3185f53

Also the same layer visualized:

http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/1416c55c575eea8be2f6/

(here in combination with visualization and validation:)
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/k8mj7eh8/

Comment: Saving as shapefile and back to geojson sanitizes the file too.